# How to check if the DateTimeControl is empty?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl CssClassTextBox="calendarItem" runat="server" ID="dateControl" DateOnly="true"></SharePoint:DateTimeControl>
```

Can you please help me to check if this control is empty in the c# code.
I want to check whether the user entered a value or not.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: tried anything so far ? Please share your code and the error logs.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: You can use lot of options using javascript, asp validators ,  code behind

Comment: Yes, I did
if (dateControl.IsDateEmpty)
{
...
}
But it didn't work

Comment: @Osi and what the problem you experienced?

Comment: It didn't work, is it a correct way?

Comment: @CoderofCode can you please show me how?

Comment: @OSI, are you aware of the type of questions you should ask in here? You cannot expect that someone reads your mind and solve it, well especially for free. You should be as specific as possible, showing some effort (best would be code) the wished output and problem/s you face.

Comment: @OSI I think the simplest solution would be to check if the control have the default value, and then take your action.

Comment: Take a look at this http://blog.sync.com.lb/265/sharepointdatetimecontrol-check-if-control-is-empty/

Comment: I've got this when trying my solution
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'PreferredContactTime'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to go about solving this issue. The easiest way to solve this issue is to utilize the isDateEmpty() method. Usage:

```
if (dateControl.IsDateEmpty) 
      // Do Something...
```

Another way to go about solving this issue is to set the isRequiredField to true. Usage:

```
dateControl.IsRequiredField = true;
```

Of course there are still several other ways to go about doing this including the use of JavaScript, forms validation, ect. These are simply the most common and easiest ways to go about solving this issue.